# One of (a,b) must be required in xml !DOCTYPE !ELEMENT

Tags: xml, dtd

Hey all,
  How do I specify two element tags such that one and only one of the tags is required?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean in an element declaration in an XML DTD?

The following declaration means that the element "name" must have exactly one "a" or "b" element.

```
<!ELEMENT name (a | b) >
```

Here's an example instance (using an internal subset instead of an external DTD):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE name [
<!ELEMENT name (a | b) >
<!ELEMENT a (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT b (#PCDATA)>
]>
<name>
  <a/>
</name>
```

Note: "(a,b)" in the title of this question would mean exactly one "a" element followed by exactly one "b" element.

Here's a schema example just in case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="name">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice>
        <xs:element ref="a"/>
        <xs:element ref="b"/>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="a" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="b" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: I believe this is what I'm looking for -- will test it out and accept later !

Comment: I also added a schema example just in case.

Comment: Is this valid syntax: <!ELEMENT Desc (tag, a?, (b | c), name?)